# Mistake in naming quadratic equation?

Tags: terminology, quadratics

cubic equation:

$$ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$$

Cube means 3.

Quadratic equation:

$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$

Quad means 4. But it is a power of two, should it be called bi... Equation.

> My question is: Is this a mistake in naming the quadratic equation?

Comment: this must have originated from the relation of the power of two to the area of a square.

Comment: square rhymes with quadrare

Comment: check this out: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151217/why-does-quadratic-describe-second-power-when-quad-means-four

Comment: "Cube" does not mean "three".

Comment: Please more upvotes on Martin's comment.

Comment: "Cubic" means of or pertaining to 3 dimensions, "quadratic" means of or pertaining to 2 dimensions, does it not?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A fourth degree polynomial is called a quartic polynomial.

Quadratic is derived from the Latin word quadratus, the past participle of quadrare, an infinitive meaning to make square.

Comment: Oh very interesting thank you for the answer

Comment: This means that the "four" from "quad" in "quadratic" refers to the four sides of a square, not to the fourth power. Interesting.

Comment: maybe quartic, from quart? @Bob1123

Comment: "Quartic" is derived from the latin word "quattuor" meaning four. The English word quart is named so because a quart is four cups. It should be noted that when the degree of a polynomial is greater than 3, the polynomial is referred to with a latin-derived name. Zeroth, first, second, and third degree polynomials are the exception (constant, linear, quadratic, and cubic, resp.).

Comment: I thought a pint was four cups. No wonder I failed my life skills test @Bob1123

Comment: @Bob1123 No, a quart is from the Latin "quartus" (quarter) and is so called because it's a quarter-gallon. (See, e.g., the OED but any dictionary should give this etymology.) The use of the word "cup" to mean a quarter of a quart is _much_ more recent: the earliest citation in the OED is from 1857, whereas "quart" goes back to the 14th Century.

Comment: @Bob1123 .  The English (and Canadian) gallon is 160 ounces and the American gallon is 128 ounces. The English (and Canadian) quart is 40 ounces and the American quart is 32 ounces. At least they have the same ounce.

Comment: @DavidRicherby thanks for the correction. I knew my Latin education wasn't great but now I'll be sure to really check these things.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet "At least they have the same ounce." Nope. An Imperial fluid ounce is 28.4ml and an American fluid ounce is 29.6ml: roughly a 5% difference. Oh, and food labels in the US use a 30ml fluid ounce.

Comment: @DavidRicherby........!!! I didn't know that.